# how to find the every single letter into the row is equal to the other row in the columns pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How to show validate in pandas each row in A and B columns is same name and last name? i am trying to make it in pandas python

Input
[image]

output
[image]

i dont have any idea

Comment: Can you please read about [the problems with images images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to convert your images of tables into markup tables? See [/editing-help#tables](/editing-help#tables) for how. You might find [tablesgenerator.com](//www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question needs some clarification as suggested by [@yeaske](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2412381/yeaske) but I feel the following code logic maybe more correct as per your input and output.

```
df['result'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['col2'].lower().startswith(row['col1'].lower()), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Always provide a code snippet on what you have already tried. At least a pseudo code.

Anyway, Give this a shot:

```
df['col3'] = df.apply(lambda row: True if row['col1'] == row['col2'] else False, axis=1)
```